# Unable to click Button after switching activity in Android

Tags: java, android

I am switching activity from SurfaceView (inside game Activity) to MenuActivity.

After I switched, my listeners are not working on my button.

```
My menu activity
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageButton startButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Switchujem","test");

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        initButtons();
    }

    public void playGame(View view){
        Constants.mediaPlayer.stop();
        Intent game = new Intent(Constants.context, GameActivity.class);
        startActivity(game);
    }

    private void initButtons(){

        //INIT PLAY BUTTON
        startButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        startButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d("Click","ME");
                switch(event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // Do something
                        startButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_clicked);
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        startButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                        playGame(startButton.getRootView());
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

GameView switching method

```
    public void update(){
        ....

        if(player.isDead()) {
            Log.d("DEAD", String.valueOf(player.isDead()));
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            Intent i = new Intent(this.context, MenuActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            thread.setRunning(false);
            ((GameActivity) context).switchScene();
        }
    }
```

GameActivity switch method

```
    public void switchScene(){
        Intent menu = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(menu);
    }
```

My game activity after i start game Run like this :
1.MainActivity -> just init some constants and run MenuActivity
2.MenuActivity ->Now everything works fine, button is clickable
3.GameActivity (with custom GameView) -> When i switch back to menu activity buttons are unclickable.

UPDATED::
I finally switch scene but after switch game crash. this is my output now:

```
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@151581e
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@d0bd591
D/Switchujem: test -> My custom output in MENU_ACTIVITY
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8faab00: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe905a910)
I/mple.doodlejum: Thread[6,tid=30588,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xe0f2a800,peer=0x145002b8,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/mple.doodlejum: Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
```

Answer (score 0):

Your callback is missed so when yo go to GameActivity they got missed, So override onResume() like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    initButtons();

}
```

Hope This Helps

Comment: Hi, this not helped me. When switching activity i alredy initButtons() in onCreate function. I think there is problem with thread with game inside surfaceView... After switch that scene it looks like game freeze for few seconds and after that it. crash... i  Updated my last output from Log.

Comment: Hi, This happens because of this https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr you need to run an App Pool so your game doesn't run on the main thread